# I have apps script file that I would like to run the functions from for every google sheet in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made a standalone apps script file that has functions such as going over the doc id column and displaying the folder path in google sheets. These sheets will be produced every month and it is time consuming to copy paste the apps script file and add it to each google sheet in the folder. I saw that stand alone scripts in the folder can be a solution but then again I would need a trigger to run and this trigger should not run if the functions have already ran.
Is there a better way to do this?

I would like to create a apps script file that attached to every google sheet in the folder and adds the functions in the UI so it can be run accordingly.

Comment: I would us a Spreadsheet as the container for my Scripts.  It's easy to create new files with Apps Script API.  It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish so I can provide you with much help.

Comment: The files are being created using GAM, it's basically drive activity report of different users in the company. We would like to have info such as folder path which does not come with the report so I am using apps script to determine the folder path based on doc id. This has to be a monthly thing where new reports would be generated for multiple teams which is why I would like to use one apps script file that attaches itself to all sheets in a folder. I hope that made it clearer.

Comment: Standalone Apps Script do not simply attach themselves to Spreadsheets.  They open the files with the method openById().  And even scripts that are contained in Spreadsheets can do that plus you get free and easy access to a great storage capability.  So yeah I would use a script in a container.